# Android singleton SQLite, IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm using SQLite with [SQLiteAssetHelper 2.0.1](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper). And I implemented a singleton DBHelper subclass like:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "...";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DB_STORAGE_DIR = "...";

    private static SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    private static DBHelper instance;

    // Create the db storage directory if it does not exist
    static {
        File dir = new File(DB_STORAGE_DIR);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.e("BEEP", "Create database folder failed! BANG!");
            }
        }
    }

    public static DBHelper getInstance(Context context){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new DBHelper(context);
        }
        return instance;
//        return new DBHelper(context);
    }

    private DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, DB_STORAGE_DIR, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        super.onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }

    public Cursor rawQuery(String query, String[] arguments){
        if(db == null || !db.isOpen()) {
            db = getReadableDatabase();
        }
        return db.rawQuery(query, arguments);
    }

    public void execute(String sql, Object[] arguments){
        if(db == null || db.isReadOnly()) {
            db = getWritableDatabase();
        }
        db.execSQL(sql, arguments);
    }

    public void close(){
        if(db != null && db.isOpen()){
            db.close();
        }
    }
}
```

And I got two reference of DBHelper instance let's say readInstance and writeInstance with the same context, and I run some sql like:

```
writeInstance.read(...);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    readInstance.read(...);
    writeInstance.write(...);    //IllegalStateException 
}
```

Then I get the IllegalStateException in the write method, which is in the DBHelper.execute method.
I tried to synchronize db in the execute method:

```
public void execute(String sql, Object[] arguments){
    if(db == null || db.isReadOnly()) {
        db = getWritableDatabase();
    }
    synchronized (db){
        db.execSQL(sql, arguments);
    }
}
```

but still getting the error.
Any advice would be helpful thanks!

Comment: Are you calling the method DBHelper::instance().close() anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found what's happening:
I didn't check the isOpen state in the execute method, and even if the db is closed, the isReadOnly method still return false, so in my former code, I used a closed db in the execute method.

**FIX:**

```
public void execute(String sql, Object[] arguments){
    if(db == null || !db.isOpen() || db.isReadOnly()) {
        db = getWritableDatabase();
    }
    db.execSQL(sql, arguments);
}
```